# UWP app running on 4K monitor crashes with E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE error

Tags: uwp

I'm going to try my best to articulate this problem...
I've got a UWP application that uses this sort of pattern to add/remove items from a ListView.

I've been trying to replicate this problem with no success.  The code below is the actual and complete code from my User Control after paring it down to the smallest bit of code that still creates the problem.

So, even though I can boil down the offending code to this smaller version of the user control, I cannot replicate the problem in a standalone app.  This might make it appear that my issue is someplace else in my application (and it may) but the problem occurs under such specific circumstances that I fear that it is impossible to completely duplicate them without creating a complete dummy project that has everything my real project has.

Here are some samples of what I can do to cause the crash to stop happening:

1. Change the height of TextBox "TxtXp" from 70 to 270.  I can't see that having any change to the application, and yet it does.  Setting the height to 270 makes the issue go way.
2. Delete StackPanel XpVp and the problem goes away.
3. Delete StackPanel PanelTitles and the problem goes away.
4. Delete StackPanel StackPanelWithNoReasonToExist and the problem goes away.
   ... you get the idea.  Making almost any change to the XAML that affects the height or the spacing of things, and the problem goes away.
5. Changing the screen resolution to 100% rather than 150%, and the problem goes away.

   ```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock
            Text="Quest Rewards" />
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="PanelXpVp"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Name="TxtXp"
                         Header="Fixed XP" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="PanelTitles">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Margin="5,10,0,0">
                        <StackPanel 
                            Name="StackPanelWithNoReasonToExist"
                            Orientation="Horizontal" Height="80">
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.CharacterTitleVms, Mode=OneWay}" 
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name" FontWeight="Bold"
                              Width="260">
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Margin="5,10,0,0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.CharacterTimedTitles, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind Vm.SelectedCharacterTimedTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                  Header="Character Timed Titles"
                                  Width="400"/>
                            <Button Content="+/-" Padding="3,0" 
                                    Click="{x:Bind Vm.AddRemoveCharacterTimedTitle}"
                                    Margin="0,28,0,0"/>
                            <Button Content="+/-" Padding="3,0" 
                                    Click="{x:Bind Vm.AddRemoveCharacterTimedTitle}"
                                    Margin="0,28,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.CharacterTimedTitleVms, Mode=OneWay}" 
                              SelectedItem="{x:Bind Vm.SelectedCharacterTimedTitleVm, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                              Width="400">
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <RelativePanel Name="PanelItemIds"
                    RelativePanel.Below="PanelTitles"
                    Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <TextBox Width="300" Height="70"/>
                <!--<AutoSuggestBox 
                    Name="CboRewardItems" 
                    UpdateTextOnSelect="False"
                    QueryIcon="Find" 
                    PlaceholderText="Search" 
                    Header="Reward Items"
                    Width="400" />-->

            </RelativePanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
   ```

This code typically works perfectly (when I'm running on an HD monitor running at 1920x1080 at 100%.)

I recently installed a 4K monitor on my system.  If I set the resolution of the monitor to 3840x2160 at 100%, the application continues to run perfectly.

However, if I set the resolution to 3840x2160 at 150%, the application crashes with the  E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE error **as soon as I delete the last item from the ListView**.  Okay, it turns out that last part isn't completely true.  It usually crashes when I delete the last item.  Sometimes it crashes when I'm deleting any item from the list.  The problem seems to be related to the reduced size of the ListView rather than just when the ListView is emptied.  In fact, while trying to isolate the problem, I've even had the app crash when adding an item to a list, but I haven't been able to effectively reproduce that problem.

However, if I take the application out of full screen mode and leave it in windowed mode, everything runs fine.

Has anybody ever seen this sort of behaviour before?  Is there a reasonable workaround for it?

Because the circumstances seem to be so finicky, I'm not sure I will ever be able to create a separate project that can consistently reproduce this issue.

Comment: If you set the resolution to 1920x1080 at 150%, will the same issue occur? In addition, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Yes, the same problem occurs at 1920x1080 at 150%.  If I can find some time to see if I can create a project to reproduce the problem I will.  But, I'm in the middle of a crunch right now, and I already lost 2 days trying to debug this issue.  From what I've seen though, I'm expecting this should be easy to reproduce.

Comment: Not easily reproduced ... the forms that I've created in my actual app are far more complicated and use many user controls.  I'm going to have to see if it's the nest controls are the root of the problem, making creating another app to reproduce this trial-and-error.  If I can free up some time, I'll keep trying different scenarios until I fall on the one that can recreate it.

Comment: When I set the resolution to 1920x1080 at 150% and run the app in full screen mode, it worked well, I didn't receive any exception when delete items. But my listview is very simple, so it's better to provide a reproduced sample to test.

Comment: This would be so much easier if you'd be willing to sign an NDA so that I can share the actual project that is having the issues rather than trying to figure out what it is in my project that makes this happen to recreate it in a new project.  If the issue is simply because of the size of my project, it makes it difficult to reproduce in a test project.  Meanwhile, I'll keep trying to find some time (and some way) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've updated the problem with a complete set of code that I'm running that creates the problem.  I've paired down the production code as much as possible, while still being able to recreate the problem.  Unfortunately, as stated in the problem description, I am unable to replicate this situation in a standalone project.

Comment: If you debug your project in mixed mode and tested it again, will there be more helpful and detailed information?

Comment: information displayed in the Debug window when it crashes: Exception thrown at 0x759E40B2 (KernelBase.dll) in Cgs.Ux.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x802B0014 : 'Windows.UI.Xaml.LayoutCycleException: E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE
E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE
   at Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledError.Propagate()
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils.ApplicationLifecycleHelper.<.ctor>b__17_1(Object sender, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs eventArgs)

Comment: plus this (it didn't all fit in one comment) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils.ApplicationLifecycleHelper.<.ctor>b__17_1(Object sender, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs eventArgs)'.

Comment: Faywang, it's been a while since you replied to this thread.  Did I provide you with sufficient information to move forward on identifying the problem?